# Find divisibility for $n \in \mathbb {Z+}, 2\nmid n, 2^n-1, 2^n +1$ w.r.t. $5$ using congruence arithmetic.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences

> Find divisibility for $n \in \mathbb {Z+}, 2\nmid n, 2^n-1, 2^n +1$ w.r.t.  $5$  using congruence arithmetic.

Checking w.r.t. modulo $5$ 
(a) $ 2^n-1$ :: $2 \equiv 2 \pmod 5\implies 2^n \equiv ........$
(b) $ 2^n+1$ :: $2 \equiv 2 \pmod 5\implies 2^n \equiv ........$

I cannot handle any case w.r.t. modulo $5$, as the only way left for me is to break $n$ into two components such that one is odd and other is even, i.e. $n=n'+1$. But that approach confuses a lot.

Comment: Well, have you worked it out for small $n$?

Comment: Well, it's hard to see a pattern if you only look at two $n$.

Comment: @lulu For (i) $n=1,$ values are: $1,3$ respectively; (ii) for $n=3$, values are : $7 \equiv 2 \pmod 5, 9 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$; (iii) for $n=5$, values are : $31 \equiv 1 \pmod 5, 33 \equiv 3 \pmod 5$; (iv) for $n=7$, values are: $127 \equiv 2 \pmod 5,129 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$; (v) for $n=9$, values are: $511 \equiv 1 \pmod 5,513 \equiv 3 \pmod 5$; (vi) for $n=11$, values are: $2047 \equiv 2 \pmod 5,2049 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$. So, the equivalence classes change from $1,3$ to $2,4$ alternatively.

Comment: Right.  Now, can you prove that?  Hint:  $2^2\equiv =-1\pmod 5$.

Comment: Worth remarking:  $2^n+1=(2^n-1)+2$ so you only need to analyze one case.  For that matter, it's probably most natural to simply compute $2^n\pmod 5$ for all $n$.

Comment: @lulu No, as it is not about any factor of $n$, but with having two separate set of equivalence classes. Am clueless about using both hints presented in two of your earlier comments. Request help, as on my basis alone, do not know when the idea clicks.

Comment: I didn't say anything about any factor of $n$.  For heaven's sakes...$2^4\equiv 1\pmod 5$.  So all you need to do is to write out $2^0,2^1,2^2,2^3$, it's periodic from there.

Comment: Right!  and that's all you need.  Worth noting, you've done more than the problem requested....the problem only addressed odd natural numbers and you have solved it for all natural numbers.

Comment: @lulu Sorry, for not realizing that. For all odd values of exponents ($n$), the pattern is : $2^1 \equiv 2 \pmod 5, 2^3 \equiv 3 \pmod 5, 2^5 \equiv 2 \pmod 5, 2^7 \equiv 3 \pmod 5,$ and the pattern repeats. But, this covers only two residue values ($2,3$) obtained earlier, i.e. out of $1,2$ and $3,4$ for $2^n-1, 2^n+1$ respectively, for odd values of $n$.

Comment: Exactly.  You actually ended up solving a more general problem, but as you (correctly) remark it isn't hard to use your solution to solve the specific problem you were asked.

Comment: @lulu I proceed by your earlier remark about finding for only one case, as the other is an addition of a residue of $2$ to that.---- So, $2+2\equiv 4 \pmod 5$, & $3+2 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$. But, the residue class taken by $2^n -1 \in \{1,2\}$, while for $2^n +1 \in \{3,4\}$. So, I am able to get : $2,4$, & $3,0$ rather than $1,2$ and $3,4$ for $2^n-1, 2^n+1$ respectively.

Comment: Well, but are you correct?  For $2^n-1$ we write out the first few terms, for odd $n$ as $1,7,31,127,\cdots$ which, $\pmod 5$ gives $1,2,1,2,\cdots$.

Comment: As you pointed out, $i\equiv 1\pmod 4\implies 2^i\equiv 2\pmod 5\implies 2^i-1\equiv 1\pmod 5$ and $i\equiv 3\pmod 4\implies 2^i\equiv 3\pmod 5\implies 2^i-1\equiv 2\pmod 5$

Comment: I am quoting you.  If $i\equiv 1 \pmod 4$, say, then we can write $i=1+4k$ for some integer $k$.  Now we write, $2^i=2^{1+4k}=2^1\times 2^{4k}=2\times \left(2^4\right)^k$ and, since $2^4\equiv 1 \pmod 5$ we see that this is $\equiv 2\times 1^k\equiv 2\pmod 5$.

Comment: It is generally true that, for $\gcd(a,m)=1$, $a^i\pmod m$ only depends on $i\pmod {\varphi(m)}$.  Of course, if $m=p$, a prime, then $\varphi(m)=p-1$.  Thus, for $m=5$, $\varphi(5)=4$.

Comment: @lulu I am confused about the application of your last comment to the problem that considers two residue classes separated by $2$ w.r.t. $5$. You have explained how there can be conversion between (both sides) modulo $4$ and $5$ by taking exponents of $2$ (or $log_2$ for opposite direction). But, the last comment that uses the multiplicative function $\varphi$ in context of the problem is not clear.

Comment: I've given you more than enough to solve the problem.  Time to roll up your sleeves and go over the comments on your own.  In fact, my last couple of comments amount to a complete solution to your problem.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $n$ is odd here. Let $n=2m-1$,

$$2^{2m-1} \equiv (2^2)^m(2^{-1})\equiv (-1)^m(3) \pmod5$$

- Hence, when $n \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, that is when $m \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$, $2^n \equiv -3 \equiv 2 \pmod{5} $
- when $n \equiv -1 \pmod{4}$, that is when $m \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$, $2^n \equiv 3 \pmod{5} $
- With those , we should be able to evaluate  $2^n \pm 1 \pmod{5}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please clarify the following: If $n=2m-1\implies n+1=2m$. So, when $n\equiv 1\pmod 4, 2m=n+1\equiv 2\pmod 4\implies 2m=n+1\equiv 0\pmod 2\implies n\equiv -1\pmod 2\implies n\equiv 1\pmod 2$. But, how to find $m$ from this last equivalence relation is not clear.       
However, for the second case, $n\equiv -1\pmod 4$, it is easy to derive $m\equiv 0\pmod 2$, as follows: $n\equiv -1\pmod 4\implies n+1\equiv 0\pmod 4\implies 2m\equiv 0\pmod 2\implies m\equiv 0\pmod 2$.

Comment: Sorry, found fault with my reasoning, as must also divide $2m$ by $2$ to get $m$ (rather than $2m$) on dividing the modulus ($4$) by $2$ in the first case.

Comment: Please see my post at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2663156/geometrical-significance-of-euclidean-algorithm-to-find-gcd-of-a-linear-dioph , for providing insight in the post.